# How to synchronize SVG animation file with audio file?

Tags: file, animation, audio, svg, synchronize

I have an SVG animation file, and I want to synchronize it with audio file (wav), any suggestions or tools to do this? and I'm using Java to generate SVG file.

any help or ideas ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `<audio>` tag for SVG but only Opera 12 supports it ATM.